# How to make array data from api values with for loop and typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I want to put the values i get back from the api with the loop in to an array that i can use latter but i am drawing a blank on how to pass the values to the array from the loop.

i have tried to pass the value to an array outside the loop but failed.

```
export let apiController = app.controller("api", function ($scope, $http) {


//https://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json
$scope.allDrivers = function () {
  console.log("I've been pressed!");
  $http.get("https://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json").then(
    function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.response = response;
      console.log("response");
      console.log(response);
    console.log("response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists.0.DriverStandings");
    console.log(response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings);

    let duzinaNiza = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings;
    console.log(parseInt(duzinaNiza.length));
    let duzinaNumber: number = parseInt(duzinaNiza.length);
    console.log(duzinaNumber);

    let nameVozaca;   // inicializacija promenjivih
    let prezimeVozaca;
    let driverPosition;
    let driverPoints;
    let i = 0;

    for (; i < duzinaNumber; i++) { // for loop is ok just fix the number issue
      nameVozaca = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].Driver.givenName;
      prezimeVozaca = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].Driver.driverId;
      driverPosition = (response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].position);
      driverPoints = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].points;

     console.log( "position " + driverPosition +  " ime Vozaca " + nameVozaca + " prezime Vozaca " + prezimeVozaca + " " + " Points " + driverPoints);



    }
}
```

i just want to have the values that are returned by the for loop added to 4 seperate arrays for future use.

Comment: You want all above value in single array ? or you want 4 different array with above value ?

Comment: nameVozaca = response.data.MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings[i].Driver.givenName; for example returns a list of names i want to put those names in an array so i can use it. same with the other values the loop returns.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer rather simple:

```
let imenaVozaca = []; outside loop for the data i want to push to array.
imenaVozaca.push(nameVozaca); in loop for the data that is being pushed

console.log("this is the array "); just a check :)
console.log(imenaVozaca);
```